# UnassignedReferenceException: The variable pointFile of HighScore has not been assigned. How do I fix this error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This error message appears when I press play on my highscore scene even though I have assigned the file.

> "UnassignedReferenceException: The variable pointFile of HighScore has
> not been assigned. You probably need to assign the pointFile variable
> of the HighScore script in the inspector."

I can't seem to find why this happens. Below is the script which is attached to the canvas in the highscore list and a picture of the connection from file to script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Linq;
public class HighScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] TextAsset pointFile;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI scoresText;
    List<string> nameList;
    string results;
    List<int> pointList;


    void Awake() {
        getItOut();
    }

    void getItOut(){
        ReadFiles();
        sortList();
        writePointsToFile(pointList, "Assets/Points.txt");

        for(int o = 0; o<5; o++){
            results += (o+1).ToString()+ ". " + pointList[o].ToString() + "\n";
        }
        scoresText.text = results;
    }

    void ReadFiles() {
        var content = pointFile.text;
        var allWords = content.Split("\n");
        List<string> tmp = new List<string>(allWords);
        pointList = tmp.ConvertAll(int.Parse);
    }

    void sortList(){
        for(int i=(pointList.Count-1); i>0; i--){
            if(pointList[i] > pointList[i-1]){
                int tmp = pointList[i];
                pointList[i] = pointList[i-1];
                pointList[i-1] = tmp;

                i = (pointList.Count-1);
            }
        }

    }

    void writePointsToFile( List<int> values, string path){
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false);
        for(int p = 0; p<5 ; p++ ){
            if(p!=4){
                 writer.Write(values[p].ToString() + "\n");
            }
            else{
                writer.Write(values[p].ToString());
            }   
        }

        writer.Flush();
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(path);
        #endif
    writer.Close();
    }
}
```

[File attached in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS5fB.png)

I have tried reconnecting it plenty of times and changing up the file but nothing works.

Comment: Once built there is no "asset" folder. So this is possibly what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is easy my friend you just need to check your inspector view where you assigned this script.

You should find 2 empty input fields :

```
 TextAsset pointFile;
 TextMeshProUGUI scoresText;
```

There you need to assign your TextAsset and Text UI from your Hierarchy View or Scene View

Comment: But that's the problem, if you see the picture I linked below the code I already assigned everything:(

Comment: I simply can reply with this Text Assets are not intended to be used for text file generation at runtime. For that you will need to use traditional Input/Output programming techniques to read and write external files. `using System.IO; `

Comment: Create a class HandleTextFile and use these functions
   `[MenuItem("Tools/Write file")]
    static void WriteString()
    {
        string path = "Assets/Resources/test.txt";
        //Write some text to the test.txt file
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        writer.WriteLine("Test");
        writer.Close();
        //Re-import the file to update the reference in the editor
        AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(path); 
        TextAsset asset = Resources.Load("test");
        //Print the text from the file
        Debug.Log(asset.text);
    }`

Comment: `[MenuItem("Tools/Read file")]
    static void ReadString()
    {
        string path = "Assets/Resources/test.txt";
        //Read the text from directly from the test.txt file
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path); 
        Debug.Log(reader.ReadToEnd());
        reader.Close();
    } ` @Maya if you have a more question like this send me an email or something I might help have fun